# How to remove a specific special character pattern from a string

Tags: java, string

I have a string name s,

```
String s = "<NOUN>Sam</NOUN> , a student of the University of oxford , won the Ethugalpura International Rating Chess Tournament which concluded on Dec.22 at the Blue Olympiad Hotel";
```

I want to remove all <**NOUN**> and <**/NOUN**> tags from the string. I used this to remove tags,

```
s.replaceAll("[<NOUN>,</NOUN>]","");
```

Yes it removes the tag. **but it also removes letter 'U' and 'O' characters from the string** which gives me following output.

```
 Sam , a student of the niversity of oxford , won the Ethugalpura International Rating Chess Tournament which concluded on Dec.22 at the Blue lympiad Hotel
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try:

```
s.replaceAll("<NOUN>|</NOUN>", "");
```

In RegEx, the syntax `[...]` will match every *character* inside the brackets, regardless of the order they appear in. Therefore, in your example, all appearances of "<", "N", "O" etc. are removed. Instead use the pipe (`|`) to match both "<NOUN>" and "</NOUN>".

The following should also work (and could be considered more DRY and elegant) since it will match the tag both with and without the forward slash:

```
s.replaceAll("</?NOUN>", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

String.replaceAll() takes a regular expression as its first argument. The regexp:

```
"[<NOUN>,</NOUN>]"
```

defines within the brackets *the set of characters* to be identified and thus removed. Thus you're asking to remove the characters `<`,`>`,`/`,`N`,`O`,`U` and comma.

Perhaps the *simplest* method to do what you want is to do:

```
s.replaceAll("<NOUN>","").replaceAll("</NOUN>","");
```

which is explicit in what it's removing. More complex regular expressions are obviously possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one regular expression for this: "<[/]*NOUN>"
so

```
s.replaceAll("<[/]*NOUN>","");
```

should do the trick. The "[/]*" matches zero or more "/" after the "<".

Comment: shouldn't that replace </////NOUN> to "" too? [/]+ would do the trick i guess?

Comment: The correct solution would be `s.replaceAll("</?NOUN>","");` since the question mark matches 0 or 1 of the preceding item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :`String result = originValue.replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");`